# What's the meaning of this sentence, "Americans aren't going to accept that this is the new normal" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

[This](https://youtu.be/Fi5Nk48zCJk) video is a debate about gun control after mass shootings in Florida. ([5:32](https://youtu.be/Fi5Nk48zCJk?t=5m32s))

> Alison: And I don't doubt that they(*Paul ryan, and the leaders of Repuplicans*) are interested (*in the issue, which is gun control and regarding regulation*). But do you sense that there will be something that happens in this week in terms of action, in terms of taking a vote?
>
> Curbelo: I think that Republican leadership is starting to realize that **Americans aren't going to accept that this is the new normal.** Americans aren't going to accept that we may drop off our kids at school one day and one day they may not come home because someone slaughter them.

There isn't any words that I don't know in this sentence, but it's hard to understand.

Is Curbelo saying that,

This (issue, or all these debate about gun control) has always been a controversial issue in American society, thus Americans never think it's a *new normal*? So, they think politicians should've already discussed this issue long while ago?

And Republican leaders are starting to realize all these only now?

Comment: Americans are not going to accept (that) this (referring to mass shooting at schools) is something routine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “new normal” in this case are the frequent school mass shootings - as elaborated in the following sentence.

Sometimes a pronoun can refer to something that will be mentioned or explained *afterwards* (instead of preceding it) or even be just implied in the general context.